# C# Attachedchild task never executes

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I have two tasks that need to execute at the same time with the top-level task ending when its child ends.

For a little more background, the child task is performing a lengthy query and the outer task is displaying a counter on the UI (via invoke) so that the user knows that something is happening.  When the child task is done it updates the UI with the results and at that point the counter (parent task) is no longer needed.  However when the tasks are started only the parent task starts, the child task never executes.  Incidentally I'm not using a BackgroundWorker for this because I need to be able to perform multiple queries/counters concurrently.

The tasks are started with a click event in a DataGridView:

```
private void hostMgmtDataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var parent = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        showTimer(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, 0);
        var child = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            winUpdate(hostMgmtDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex);
        },TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
    });
}
```

This syntax is taken from the following article:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997417(v=vs.100).aspx

If I add parent.Wait(); as described in the above article the whole UI thread locks up, which is not a desirable result.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I tried using the example code from the article (adapted a little for my form):

```
var parent = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    debugLabel1.Invoke(new Action(() => debugLabel1.Text = "parent starting"));

    var child = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        debugLabel2.Invoke(new Action(() => debugLabel2.Text = "child starting"));
        Thread.SpinWait(5000000);
        debugLabel2.Invoke(new Action(() => debugLabel2.Text = "child stopped"));
    },TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
});
parent.Wait();
debugLabel1.Text = "parent stopped";
```

Once again if I leave in parent.Wait() the UI thread locks up.  If I take out the Wait statement "parent stopped" never displays, but "child stopped" does.

Upon further reading a lot of people are suggesting to use "ContinueWith" but I need both Tasks to run concurrently, Continuation runs the tasks sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

your locking might be caused by the UI change implementation.
I can achieve the same using tasks using this;

```
 var context = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
            var parent = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {

            Task.Delay(40000);
                MessageBox.Show("From Parent");
            var child = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>{
                MessageBox.Show("From Child");
                Task.Delay(30000);
                Text = "Title change from Child";
            });
            }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent, context);
```

Edit:See Evk comment below in regards to the following statement

Also, If you are using framework 4.5, I recommend using Task.Run instead of Task.Factory.StartNew... See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/10/24/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/ for more details

Comment: Note that in this particular case advice about Task.Run is not a good one, because Task.Run calls StartNew with options DenyChildAttach, so will actually prevent attaching child tasks.

Comment: I tried your code to no avail - it locks up the UI thread :(

If I take out CancellationToken.None and context, the UI thread doesn't get locked up but the child task doesn't execute, just like before.

Could it be something about starting these tasks from an event handler that's causing these issues?

Comment: It's hard to give you an answer without seeing the code used for the other methods